# Is using newsequentialid bad?

Tags: owasp, sql-server

I found a project that uses T-SQL's `newsequentialid()` for one of their external ID columns which is used for public APIs.

When that column is added to an existing table, each row gets an incremented GUID.

Is this bad?

A malicious user could quickly work out that the GUID is incremented and predict GUIDs for entities in the DB.

Is there some other reason to use `newsequentialid()` over `newid()` that I've missed that would warrant not following [security best practices](https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References)?

Answer (score 2):

Your security should not be reliant on a the ID of an object being secret - you should be enforcing proper access control so that it doesn't matter if an attacker can guess them.

Sequential IDs may be beneficial for various performance-related reasons (for example, they're automatically sorted by creation date, and don't require an RNG to generate) - which may be relevant for some applications.

Comment: This is true. However "best practices" (from OWASP) still recommends to avoid sequential IDs wherever possible because it is a (minor) information leak.

Comment: you'd only leak information if the access control leaked information.  (So if a user has no access to something it doesn't reveal that they guessed an actual ID, either by timing or directly telling them that this record exists but they have no access...)

Comment: @pcalkins This is true. However "best practices" (from OWASP) still recommends to avoid sequential IDs wherever possible, for defence in depth.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner to be more specific, an OWASP document from 2013 (which doesn't justify why) recommended it. The current OWASP Top 10 [entry](https://owasp.org/Top10/A01_2021-Broken_Access_Control/) and [ASVS entry](https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/blob/v4.0.3/4.0/en/0x12-V4-Access-Control.md) do not include that recommendation.